# How to use a method call as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

In C#, how to pass a method as parameter of another method, by passing the parameters with the called method, in order to call that method inside, having, for example, the goal of measuring its execution?

Could the code be close to the following pseudo-code?

```
public TR MeasureExecutionTime<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, TR>(this Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, TR> func, out long executionTime)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    TR tr = func();

    stopwatch.Stop();

    executionTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    return tr;
}

...

var result = MeasureExecutionTime(() => obj.Process(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6), out long executionTime);
```

The main problem here seems to be how to pass and deduce the callee parameters p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6. How could this be written as flexible and simple as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the arguments when you create the lambda to be timed rather than inside the method that's doing the timing.

So you can implement the timing function like so (using a tuple to return two values):

```
public static (TimeSpan duration, T result) TimeFunction<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var result = func();
    return (sw.Elapsed, result);
}
```

You would use that to time a function with multiple parameters like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Note how we apply the parameters here, even though the 
            // function is actually called inside TimeFunction().

            var result = TimeFunction(() => functionToTime(1, 2.0, "3"));

            Console.WriteLine("Result = "   + result.value);
            Console.WriteLine("Duration = " + result.duration);
        }

        static string functionToTime(int intVal, double doubleVal, string stringVal)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(250);
            return $"intVal = {intVal}, doubleVal = {doubleVal}, stringVal = {stringVal}";
        }

        public static (TimeSpan duration, T value) TimeFunction<T>(Func<T> func)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var result = func();
            return (sw.Elapsed, result);
        }
    }
}
```

This approach is similar to "partial function application", [as discussed in this article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/01/30/currying-vs-partial-function-application/).

Note: If you can't use tuples because you're using an older version of C#, you would have to declare the timing method like this:

```
public static T TimeFunction<T>(Func<T> func, out TimeSpan duration)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var result = func();
    duration = sw.Elapsed;

    return result;
}
```

and change the calls to it accordingly.

Comment: Indeed, I use an old C# version, so I can use only the second syntax. Now, I have realized why my attempts didn't work. Thank you!